# Working on local host wamp server

Tags: php, internet-explorer, wampserver

I want to show pdf files on my webpage and using this code

```
<a href=\"C:\wamp\www\web\books\T.A._Brown_Genomes_3__2006.pdf\"type="application/pdf">book</a>
```

But I'm getting this error below

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /"C:/wamp/www/asli/books/T.A._Brown_Genomes_3__2006.pdf/"title= on this server.
```

How to fix this error??

2) When I try this code

```
<!--Embed PDF File-->
<object data="C:\wamp\www\asli\books\T.A._Brown_Genomes_3__2006.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

I am getting message in pop up window (PDF acess denied) why is this so.

Comment: Access the .pdf files **from your webserver**, not from the local filesystem

Answer (score 1):

The data URL should point to something under your www, for exemple, if you have `localhost:8080/yourfolder/` in your URL, and a file under `c:/wamp/www/yourfolder/some.pdf` the the data should point to `data="http://localhost:8080/yourfolder/some.pdf"` (or relative URL) and not to the physical place of the file like you are doing.

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it as answered.